# How can I get only the city name from geocoder?

Tags: javascript, geolocation, google-geocoder

I'm a very very very beginner in javascript.
I'm building an app and decided to implement some geolocation features, the main one is to show the user his current locaition.
I did it, but my function returns a full adress (like street, number, neighborhood, city, zip code and country)
This is what is done so far...

```
/* CURRENT LOCATION */
function geolocationSuccess(position) {
  var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
  var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = {lat: latitude, lng: longitude};

  geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[0]){
        var user_address = results[0].formatted_address;
        document.getElementById("current_location").innerHTML = user_address;
      }else {
        console.log('No results found for these coords.');
      }
    }else {
      console.log('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function geolocationError() {
  console.log("please enable location for this feature to work!");
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(geolocationSuccess, geolocationError);
  } else {
    alert("Geolocation not supported!");
  }
});
```

How can I get and show just the city?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're returning the full address:

```
var user_address = results[0].formatted_address;
```

instead you need to iterate thru the address components and find the `locality`:

```
var user_city = results[0].address_components.filter(ac=>~ac.types.indexOf('locality'))[0].long_name
```

The data structure is shown here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Comment: Just another thing, please...
What would be this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'long_name' of undefined"?
my guess is that I exceeded the limits of requests of a day, and now it doesn't return anything

Comment: @EdiJunior - that is most likely the case, yes. you can sign up for a paid api key and it will continue to work.

Comment: Edi this is not necessarily the case, it could be because there is no locality type returned by google. In this case I would then loop through result[1] etc.

Answer (score 1):

The result has `address_components` property. And it contains city, zip, etc ...

For example, in the official documentation, this is the content of address_components:

```
[
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ]
```

If you want to get `locality` for example, just do

```
 result[0].address_components.filter(address => address.types.includes('locality'))[0].long_name
```

Comment: locality won't always be the third item. you need to loop thru and find it.

Comment: locality won't always be there, in which case you'd need to loop through all the results. In my case I have 15 results.